# How to insert values using soap in android

Tags: android, soap

If i have a Results method inside HCL method as shown below.Then how to insert value into datecollect using soap in android

```
<HCL xmlns="http://www.tcpip.riv.in/">
  <Results>
    <datecollect>string</datecollect>
  </Results>
</HCL>
```

Comment: webservices are build in Dot.net ?

Comment: ofcourse webservices are build in dot.net!! but i want to  insert values from android ..

Comment: @Dr.nik it's not relevant ... @Sando 1. don't yell, it's not obvious, soap webservices can be done in any language ... `Results method inside HCL method` ?? `Results` seems to be object that you should pass to function

Comment: Here is my exact requirement..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762800/how-can-i-pass-data-for-nested-xml-tag-for-soap-base-service-android

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send value to server from soap object?

If yes then use the following:

```
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://www.tcpip.riv.in/","HCL");
   request.addProperty("datecollect",valueToInsert);
```

Comment: can u paste all that snippet which u r using to post to server

Comment: here is my exact requirement  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762800/how-can-i-pass-data-for-nested-xml-tag-for-soap-base-service-android